# Problem proving connected subspace of complex plane touches real line

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

I've stated the problem hereunder and my ideas, but I feel that I'm missing something in my proof. I'm not sure that my argument of "forcing connection" is actually a proof that my 4 conditions really **imply** the wanted implication.

Thanks in advance !

Question:

If

1. $\Omega \subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ open
2. $\Omega \neq \varnothing $
3. $\Omega$ connected
4. $z \in \Omega \Leftrightarrow \bar{z} \in \Omega$

Then $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R} \neq \varnothing$

**My proof:**

Let $\Omega $ by as described in 1. to 4. but with one more condition: $\Omega\cap \mathbb{R} = \varnothing$

1. *We prove that in fact $\Omega$ is not connected:*
   $\mathbb{H} = \{  x+i y \in \mathbb{C}$ $|$ $y>0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$
   $\overline{\mathbb{H}} = \{  x+i y \in \mathbb{C}$ $|$ $y<0\}$ also
   $\mathbb{H} \cup \overline{\mathbb{H}}$ recovers $\Omega$ disjointly $\Rightarrow \Omega$ not connected
2. *This construction is not possible: We want to force the connection condition*
3. We choose any $z_{0} \in \Omega$ and we define $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be a continuous path with $\gamma(0) = z_{0}$ and $\gamma(1) = \overline{z_{0}}$
4. Let $\Gamma := \gamma([0,1])$.  We now know from the continuity of $\gamma$ that  $\Gamma \cap \mathbb{R}$ is not empty.
5. Let $A := \Omega \cup \Gamma$. $A$ fulfills everything stated in the above conditions 1. to 4. and $A \cap \mathbb{R} \neq \varnothing$

qed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you are doing. But your point $1.$ is essentially sufficient for the proof of the following stronger fact:

Let $\Omega$ be any subset of $\mathbb{C}$, containing at least one point in $\mathbb{H}$ and one point in $\bar{\mathbb{H}}$. Then if $\Omega$ is connected, $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$ is not empty. (Remark that I don't assume that $\Omega$ is open).

The proof is that $(\Omega \cap \mathbb{H}) \cup (\Omega \cap \bar{\mathbb{H}})$ is a disjoint union of non-empty open sets in $\Omega$, which is equal to $\Omega$ (contradicting the connectivity) if $\Omega$ does not intersect $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is indeed much stronger. The only thing which isn't clear for me in your explanation is: why are $\Omega \cap \mathbb{H}$ and $\Omega \cap \overline{\mathbb{H}}$ open ?

Comment: This is the definition of the topology on a subspace: if $X$ is a subset of a topological space $Y$, the opens in $X$ are the intersections $U \cap X$, with $U$ open in $Y$. Here $X$ is $\Omega$, $Y$ is $\mathbb{C}$ and $U$ is for instance $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: OK this means that $X$ is connected iff $X$ cannot be written as the disjoint union of two nonempty open (in $X$ !) sets ? I thought that in the definition the "open" word would signify open in $Y$

Comment: No connectedness in an instrinsic property of the topological subspace $X$. It does not depend on the inclusion $X \subset Y$ (but of course, here, the topology on $X$ is defined by this inclusion).

Comment: Found the answer on wikipedia :-) "A subset of a topological space is said to be connected if it is connected under its subspace topology."(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by how you're going about your proof. You prove that such an $\Omega$ is not possible since it not connected, but then you modify it regardless? How do you know that $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$?

A more straightforward proof might be thus: first, prove an [open, connected subset of $\mathbb C$ is path connected](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected) (which you seem to assume anyway?). Second, prove that any path going from $z$ to $\bar z$ must pass through $\mathbb R$. Since some path between these two points is contained in $\Omega$, a point on $\mathbb R$ must be in $\Omega$.